# WSO2 IS/AM- Is there an option to configure SMS OTP for users in secondary store?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are building a mobile application and one of the use cases is to send SMS OTP when the user forgets his/her password.

Is there a way to trigger SMS OTP from WSO2 Identity Server/API Manager for users available in the secondary store?

Answer (score 0):

> We are building a mobile application and one of the use cases is to send SMS OTP when the user forgets his/her password.

WSO2 IS has provided `preferred channel` option (Either SMS or Email) for recovery notifications for 5.7.0 (As an update, which you might need a paid subscription), and for 5.10.0 without any updates. [Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Extending+User+Self+Registration+and+Account+Confirmation)

However, this is not supported via the default UI flow. Rather, you have to use the account recovery REST APIs as in this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Using+Account+Recovery+REST+APIs).

Basically, if the user account contains a 'preferredChannel' claim value (Either `SMS` or `EMAIL`), during this recovery flow (using the REST APIs), notification will be sent through their preferred channel.